# freeware for generating diagrams

Tags: java, uml

Do you know any nice freeware that will take my java sources and will generate class diagrams from them?

Comment: This should go in the wiki for the sheer number of useful answers.

Answer (score 6):

Last year, I wrote this small tool : **java2dot** . It generates a file for [graphviz dot](http://www.graphviz.org/).
See http://plindenbaum.blogspot.com/2008/10/javadoc-is-not-enough-java2dia.html

[image: https://media.tumblr.com/NngfN9gsDfci6h2zSjZtnUPko1_500.jpg]

Hope it helps

Comment: Off-topic but I recently had an experience (no, that's not a punctuation error nor typo) with Jena, do you happen to be affiliated with it? :)

Comment: No, but I've played with the Jena API.

Comment: Great job. Looks great I will download your code and see.

Answer (score 4):

Netbeans has a [UML plugin](http://www.netbeans.org/features/uml/index.html) that can reverse engineer class diagrams from Java source.

Answer (score 4):

[Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) can do that (with help from Graphviz).

Looks like there's a nice tutorial for installing and configuring it, including details about annotations to use for it, [here](http://www.cypax.net/tutorials/doxygen/index?language=en).

Answer (score 2):

[StarUML](http://staruml.sourceforge.net/en/)

Answer (score 1):

This may be more than what you asked for, but [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) use the "dot" tool from graphviz to generate class diagram along the documentation of any java application.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Fujaba](http://www.fujaba.de/). It supports forward engineering (UML -> Java) and reverse engineering (Java -> UML). Class diagrams are supported.

[image]
<sub>(source: [fujaba.de](http://www.fujaba.de/fileadmin/Informatik/Fujaba/Resources/Screenshots/Fujaba4.gif))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

[ArgoUML](http://argouml.tigris.org/) can create class diagrams from Java. However last time I used it (a fair time back now) it did not do all that great a job at laying it all out.

Answer (score 0):

[TopCoder UML Tool](http://www.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=dev&d2=umltool&d3=description)

Answer (score 0):

If you use maven, one nice way of generating UML from your classes is by generating JavaDocs and adding the UMLGraph doclet. See the following link:

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/examples/alternate-doclet.html

The nice thing about this is that it becomes simple to integrate into a nightly build.

Answer (score 0):

[Slime](http://www.slimeuml.de/) is a neat small UML plugin for eclipse that can draw class diagrams.

Answer (score 0):

[AmaterasUML](http://amateras.sourceforge.jp/cgi-bin/fswiki_en/wiki.cgi?page=AmaterasUML) is a free eclipse plugin that works pretty well. You can drag and drop classes from the package explorer to the diagram, and export to png.

Answer (score 0):

ArgoUML is the best free UML tool.  MagicDraw is the best commercial UML tool. And IDEs have plugins to create UML diagrams too (Eclipse and Netbeans to name two).

Answer (score 0):

I use the [ObjectAID UML plugin](http://www.objectaid.com/) for eclipse.  It's a very nice free tool that lets you build UML diagrams that you can navigate.

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600097/uml-diagram-tool-eclipse-plug-in/2600272#2600272) for more Eclipse plugins that allow you to do this with UML.