# UML Diagram Tool - Eclipse plugin?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, uml, class-diagram

Can anyone help me? I am currently using Eclipse Java IDE, and would like a plug-in that will automatically look at my classes and draw up a class diagram in UML.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I recommend the [ObjectAid UML plugin](http://www.objectaid.com/).  It works very nicely.

Comment: Hi, I installed this tool, got it working etc, but can you get it to sort of draw up everything automatically like assosiations and what not?

Comment: Once you create your diagram (New > Other > ObjectAID UML Diagram), then right click to add the classes you want to show. Then select all and right click to add relationships.

Comment: how to export the diagram as image?

Comment: No, but you can evaluate it before purchase. http://www.objectaid.com/install-license

Comment: This is not a freeware and the license expires in 2 days.

Comment: not able to add any class. it just shows blank canvas. neither with new wizard nor with add java classifier. Using eclipse neon and having license

Answer (score 4):

The challenge in what you are trying to do is that you can have multiple correct UML diagrams for any piece of code. Just trying to automatically get a diagram ends up with too much garbage when using most UML tools - and the tools just end up getting in the way.

We created [Architexa](http://www.architexa.com) to help in this situation - Architexa helps you to get to useful diagrams fast - if that means connecting to source code commits or even building layered architectural diagrams. A good discussion on some of the things that you might be looking for can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871449/what-tools-should-i-use-to-visualize-structure-of-my-code/3878175#3878175).

Answer (score 2):

Try [UML2 from Eclipse Modeling Tools](http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/mdt/?project=uml2). Here's also a [tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/UML/article.html).

Answer (score 1):

Even if a bit too late for the original questioner, maybe following eclipse plugin does match the need of real time analysis:

http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/javadoc-uml-view

This tool is highly intended for analysis purposes and less for diagram modeling. So if you want to draw diagrams manually its not the right one, in this case ObjectAid UML explorer is far better.

Just to be mentioned :-)

Answer (score 1):

One more option: http://www.modelgoon.org/

It's a very simple one, but it's still an active project.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Omondo](http://www.uml2.org/). Its a very nice UML plugin for eclipse. It will exactly suit your needs

Comment: @Bragaadeesh: Doesn't seem to be free though (???)

Comment: It is not free but you have a 90 days license in the latest SR2 build. Plenty of time to finish your project. No nagscreen, no tag in the code, the uml model is standard and could therefore be open by any tool. Only the graphical editor is under the 90 days evaluation. So not so bad :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would try MoDisco http://www.eclipse.org/gmt/modisco/. It is an extensible framework for software modernization.

Comment: I didn't find a straightforward way to generate a UML diagram out of the code of a project with MoDisco.

Comment: MoDisco uses an intermediate Java model to avoid losing any information when going from the code to the model. There is a predefined transformation to go from this Java model to a UML class diagram showing the classes. Maybe you could ask in the Modisco forum for pointers

Comment: So there isn't a straightforward way :). Thanks anyway for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You may try [architexa](http://www.architexa.com/) tool suite. It generates not only class/sequence diagrams but also layered diagrams. You may read about it [here](http://deathbycode.blogspot.in/2012/08/architexa.html).

Answer (score 0):

Check this out, this designer is free (Open Source with EPL license).

[UML Designer](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/uml-designer) which can be used for:

- Package Hierarchy
- Class Diagam
- Component Diagram
- Composite Structure Diagram
- Deployment Diagram
- Use Case Diagram
- Activity Diagram
- State Machine
- Sequence Diagram
- Profile Diagram

Got good tutorial as well:

http://www.umldesigner.org/tutorials/tuto-getting-started.html

Answer (score -1):

If you can move to IntelliJ they have a wonderful plugin for that.

If you're "stuck" with eclipse... [AmaterasUML](http://amateras.sourceforge.jp/cgi-bin/fswiki_en/wiki.cgi?page=AmaterasUML) is good enough - I've used it in the past...

Comment: NetBeans also has great UML plugin. :-)

Comment: @Bozhidar which plugin would that be? looking it up I found several available.. could you post a link to your favorite?

Comment: NetBeans UML support is deprecated, as far as i know (not included in 6.8 anymore).