# How should I visualize the structure of my code?

Tags: java, schema, uml, code-structure, code-visualization

I have an application written in Java. In is stored in several files. It uses different classes with different methods. The code is big and complicated. I think it would be easier to understand the code if I have a graphical model of the code (some kind of directed graph). Are there some standard methods for visualization of code. I am thinking about usage of UML (not sure it is a correct choice). Can anybody recommend me something?

**ADDED:**

I consider two possibilities:

1. Creating the graph by hands (explicitly).
2. Creating graph in an automatic way. For example to use some tools that read the available code and generate some graph describing the structure of the code.

**ADDED 2:**

It would be nice to have something for free.

Comment: This question is not about recommending a book, tool, software library, tutorial, or other off-site resource.  This question is about help with a process.  At some point, everyone has to deal with a large unfamiliar codebase, and this question is all about asking where to start.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**The most important tool you should use is your brain, and it's free.**

There's no reason why you have to use any sort of standard method of visualization, and you can use whatever media you like. Paper, whiteboard, photoshop, visio, powerpoint, notepad: all of these can be effective.  Draw a diagram of classes, objects, methods, properties, variables - whatever you think is useful to see in order to understand the application.  The audience is not only other members of your team, but also yourself.  Create diagrams that are useful for you to look at and quickly understand.  Post them around your workspace and look at them regularly to remind yourself of the overall system architecture as you build it.

UML and other code documentation standards are good guidelines for the types of diagrams you can do and the information you should consider including.  However, it is overkill for most applications and basically exists for people who can't take personal responsibility for documenting without standards.  If you follow UML to the letter, you'll end up spending way too much time on your documentation instead of creating your application.

Comment: don't disagree with overall sentiment but would take issue with "[UML]...exists for people who can't take personal responsibility for documenting without standards".  UML provides a common graphical syntax.  Using a standard syntax saves needlessly inventing your own and having to explain it to other parties.  It doesn't fit in all cases and shouldn't be slavishly followed.  But to suggest it's a recourse for irresponsibility is wrong.

Comment: It's not the UML that's the problem; it's thinking that auto generating diagrams is sufficient that's wrong.

Comment: There are many reasons why people can't take personal responsibility for documenting without standards.  Irresponsibility is one of them, but I think a lack of experience is much more common.

Comment: I definitely agree with @duffymo. I would add that one of the things that Architexa has tried to do differently is that it explicitly assumes that any diagrams are the starting point of exploration as opposed to the final result.

Comment: I don't think we view things the same way, Erick.  I'm not a documentation hound.

Comment: @duffymo: I think we agree enough. As long as the developer is actively thinking about the documentation from the perspective of the person who has to use it, good documentation will be produced.  Blindly following a standard or generating some diagrams is simply not sufficient.

Comment: Start with UML, continue with brain..

Answer (score 25):

I tried using a number of UML tools and found that the reverse-engineering capabilities in most UML tools were **not helpful for understanding code**. They focus on designing needs and reverse-engineering capabilities often just ends up showing huge pictures of lots of useless information. When I was working on the Microsoft Office codebase, I found using a pen-and-paper more helpful that the typical design/modelling tools.

You typically want to think about doing this in a number of ways:

1. **Use your brain**: Someone else mentioned it - there is no substitute to actually trying to understand a code base. You might need to take notes down and refer back to it later. Can tools help? Definitely. But don't expect them to do most of the work for you.
2. **Find documentation and talk to co-workers**: There is no better way than having some source describe the main *concepts* in a codebase. If you can find someone to help you, take a pen and paper, go to him and take lots of notes. How much to bug the other person? In the beginning - as much as is practical for your work, but no amount is too little.
3. **Think about tools**: If you are new to a part of a project - you are going to be spending a  significant amount of time understanding the code, so see how much help you can get automatically. There are good tools and bad tools. Try to figure out which tools have capabilities that might be helpful for you first. As I mentioned above, the average UML tool focuses more on modeling and does not seem to not be the right fit for you.
4. **Time vs Cost**: Sure, free is great. But if a free tool is not being used by many people - it might be that the tool does not work. There are many tools that were create just as an exploration of what could be done, but are not really helpful and therefore just made available for free in hopes that someone else will adopt it. Another way to think about it, decide how much your time is worth - it might make sense to spend a day or two to get a tool to work for you.

Once there, keep these in mind when going trying to understand the project:

1. **The Mile High View**: A layered architectural diagram can be really helpful to know how the main *concepts* in a project are related to one another. Tools like **[Lattix](http://www.lattix.com)** and **[Architexa](http://www.architexa.com)** can be really helpful here.
2. **The Core**: Try to figure out how the code works with regards to the *main concepts*. Class diagrams are exceptionally useful here. Pen-and-paper works often enough here, but tools can not only speed up the process but also help you save and share such diagrams. I think **[AgileJ](http://www.agilej.com)** and **[Architexa](http://www.architexa.com)** are your best bets here, but your average UML tool can often be good enough.
3. **Key Use Cases**: I would suggest tracing atleast one key use case for your app. You likely can get the most important use cases from anyone on your team, and stepping through it will be really helpful. Most IDE's are really helpful here. If you try drawing them, then sequence diagrams arethe most appropriate. For tools here I think **[MaintainJ](http://www.maintainj.com/)**, **[JDeveloper](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/overview/index.html)** and **[Architexa](http://www.architexa.com)** are your best bets here.

Note: I am the founder of Architexa - we build tools to help you **[understand and document Java code](http://www.architexa.com)**, but I have tried to be unbiased above. My intention is to suggest tools and options given that this is what I focused on as part of my PhD.

Comment: All of the tools mentioned are for Eclipse. The question is about visualizing java.

Answer (score 15):

> > It is stored in several files. It uses different classes with different methods. The code is big and complicated.

All Java code written outside the school is like that, particularly for a new developer starting on a project.

This is an old question, but as this is coming up in Google searches, I am adding my response here so that it could be useful to the future visitors. Let me also disclose that I am the author of [MaintainJ](http://maintainj.com).

**Don't try to understand the whole application**

Let me ask you this - why do you want to understand the code? Most probably you are fixing a bug or enhancing a feature of the application. The first thing you should not try to do is to understand the whole application. Trying to understand the entire architecture while starting afresh on a project will just overwhelm you.

Believe me when I say this - developers with 10+ years of solid coding experience may not understand how certain parts of the application work even after working on the same project for more than a year (assuming they are not the original developers). They may not understand how the authentication works or how the transaction management works in the application. I am talking about typical enterprise applications with 1000 to 2000 classes and using different frameworks.

**Two important skills required to maintain large applications**

Then how do they survive and are paid big bucks? Experienced developers usually understand what they are doing; meaning, if they are to fix a bug, they will find the location of the bug, then fix it and make sure that it does not break the rest of the app. If they need to enhance a feature or add a new feature, most of the time, they just have to imitate an existing feature that does a similar thing.

There are two important skills that help them to do this.

1. They are able to analyze the impact of the change(s) they do while fixing a bug. First they locate the problem, change the code and test it to make sure that it works. Then, because they know the Java language well and the frameworks 'well enough', they can tell if it will break any other parts of the app. If not, they are done.
2. I said that they simply need to imitate to enhance the application. To imitate effectively, one needs to know Java well and understand the frameworks 'well enough'. For example, when they are adding a new Struts Action class and adding to the configuration xml, they will first find a similar feature, try to follow the flow of that feature and understand how it works. They may have to tweak a bit of the configuration (like the 'form' data being in 'request' than in 'session' scope). But if they know the frameworks 'well enough', they can easily do this.

The bottom line is, **you don't need to understand** what all the 2000 classes are doing to fix a bug or enhance the app. Just understand what's needed.

**Focus on delivering immediate value**

So am I discouraging you from understanding the architecture? No, not at all. All I am asking you is to deliver. Once you start on a project and once you have set up the development environment on your PC, you should not take more than a week to deliver something, however small it may be. If you are an experienced programmer and don't deliver anything after 2 weeks, how can a manager know if you really working or reading sports news?

So, to make life easier for everyone, **deliver** something. Don't go with the attitude that you need to understand the whole application to deliver something valuable. It's completely false. Adding a small and localized Javascript validation may be very valuable to the business and when you deliver it, the manager feels relieved that he has got some value for his money. Moreover, it gives you the time to read the sports news.

As time passes by and after you deliver 5 small fixes, you would start to slowly understand the architecture. Do not underestimate the time needed to understand each aspect of the app. Give 3-4 days to understand the authentication. May be 2-3 days to understand the transaction management. It really depends on the application and your prior experience on similar applications, but I am just giving the ballpark estimates. Steal the time in between fixing the defects. Do not ask for that time.

When you understand something, write notes or draw the class/sequence/data model diagram.

**Diagrams**

Haaa...it took me so long to mention diagrams :). I started with the disclosure that I am the author of MaintainJ, the tool that generates runtime sequence diagrams. Let me tell you how it can help you.

The big part of maintenance is to locate the source of a problem or to understand how a feature works.

MaintainJ generated sequence diagrams show the call flow and data flow for a single use case. So, in a simple sequence diagram, you can see which methods are called for a use case. So, if you are fixing a bug, the bug is most probably in one of those methods. Just fix it, ensure that it does not break anything else and get out.

If you need to enhance a feature, understand the call flow of that feature using the sequence diagram and then enhance it. The enhancement may be like adding an extra field or adding a new validation, etc. Usually, adding new code is less risky.

If you need to add a new feature, find some other feature similar to what you need to develop, understand the call flow of that feature using MaintainJ and then imitate it.

Sounds simple? It is actually simple, but there will be cases where you will be doing larger enhancements like building an entirely new feature or something that affects the fundamental design of the application. By the time you are attempting something like that, you should be familiar with the application and understand the architecture of the app reasonably well.

**Two caveats to my argument above**

1. I mentioned that adding code is less risky than changing existing code. Because you want to avoid changing, you may be tempted to simply copy an existing method and add to it rather than changing the existing code. Resist this temptation. All applications have certain structure or 'uniformity'. Do not ruin it by bad practices like code duplication. You should know when you are deviating from the 'uniformity'. Ask a senior developer on the project to review the changes. If you must do something that does not follow the conventions, at least make sure that it's local to a small class (a private method in a 200 line class would not ruin the application's esthetics).
2. If you follow the approach outlined above, though you can survive for years in the industry, you run the risk of not understanding the application architectures, which is not good in the long run. This can be avoided by working on bigger changes or by just less Facebook time. Spend time to understand the architecture when you are a little free and document it for other developers.

**Conclusion**

Focus on immediate value and use the tools that deliver that, but don't be lazy. Tools and diagrams help, but you can do without them too. You can follow my advice by just taking some time of a senior developer on the project.

Comment: good information, useful stuff.

Comment: Sorry, too much redundant information and like an essay. SO should also make sure the answers, like questions are specific.

Comment: Yeah, great idea, let's not just vandalize and subjectively edit questions.. let's also modify and screw with the answers people worked hard to write up... SO community has some serious mindset issues.

Answer (score 10):

Some plugins I know for Eclipse:

**Architexa**

http://www.architexa.com/

**nWire**

http://www.nwiresoftware.com/

If you want to reverse engineer the code, you should try **[Enterprise Architect](http://www.sparxsystems.com/products/ea/index.html)**

Answer (score 9):

have you tried [Google CodePro Analytix](https://developers.google.com/java-dev-tools/codepro/doc/) ?

it can for example display dependencies and is free (screenshot from cod.google.com):

[image: Screenshot from Google]

Comment: The link in this page is broken. I add the correct link: [CodePro Analytix User Guide](https://developers.google.com/java-dev-tools/codepro/doc/)

Answer (score 4):

Here is a non UML Tool which has very nice visualization features.

You can mapping the lines of code per class / method to colors / side lenght of rectangles.
You can also show the dependencies between the classes.

http://www.moosetechnology.org/

The nice thing is, you can use Smalltalk scripting for displaying what you need:
http://www.moosetechnology.org/docs/faq/JavaModelManipulation

Here you can see how such a visualization looks like:
http://www.moosetechnology.org/tools/moosejee/casestudy

Answer (score 3):

[JUDE Community UML](http://jude.change-vision.com/jude-web/product/community.html) used to be able to import Java, but it is no longer the case.  It is a good, free tool.

If your app is really complex I think that diagrams won't carry you very far.  When diagrams become very complex they become hard to read and lose their power.  Some well chosen diagrams, even if generated by hand, might be enough.

You don't need every method, parameter, and return value spelled out.  Usually it's just the relationships and interactions between objects or packages that you need.

Comment: It is true, when I last time tried to create UML from code.. the resulted diagrams are too complicated to understand. It is easier to understand code directly.

Comment: That's why I don't care much for UML or reverse engineering.  The diagrams don't often create themselves.

Comment: I fully agree with you, this is why it is important to be able to navigate inside a model. UML tools only display a class diagram  in which you can not navigate. What I like is to drag and drop a class and look at its interaction by selecting class show dependencies, show association, be able to hide them and then look at something else. It is always the same diagram but you can hide the size of the class, hide compartments etc..;and a very very large code is clearly visible. Now that I use EclipseUML Omondo I can do it and my job in my company is better because my code is better.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a another tool that could do the trick:
http://xplrarc.massey.ac.nz/

Answer (score 2):

You can use [JArchitect](http://www.jarchitect.com/) tool, a pretty complete tool to visualize your code structure using the [dependency graph](http://www.jarchitect.com/Doc_VS_Arch), and browse you source code like a database using [CQlinq](http://www.jarchitect.com/cqlinq).
JArchitect is free for [open source contributors](http://www.jarchitect.com/jarchitectForOSS)

Answer (score 0):

Some great tools I use -

StarUML (allows code to diagram conversion)

MS Visio

XMind (very very useful for overview of the system)

Pen and Paper!