# Google Cloud Datastore: is it possible to "visualize" data entities in UML style?

Tags: database, google-app-engine, uml, schema, google-cloud-datastore

My collegues have created a series of entities using ["Google Cloud Datastore"](https://developers.google.com/datastore/).

What I would like to achieve now is to **generate a data schema from the set of entities we have got**. Something like [this](http://support.smartbear.com/images/support/kb/data/2011/1/31/info-database-schema.jpg).

It does not necessarily have to include the 1:1, 1:many, n:n archs but a UML style data structure generated for each entity would be already a good start.

The **challenge** is that:

- when clicking on a "record" when colums are empty a data type does not show
- some colum fields are "objects" (which can be complex JSON objects, not sure if I would prefer to model them as a separate entity and link them to it or to leave the word "object")
- referencing between record is done by the developer and I doubt that there is a tool clever enough to understand this. Hence I do not expect to have also hte n:n relations shown.

**Is there a project or a tool or a methodology to create this schema starting from an existing "Google Cloud Datastore"**?

Comment: there are graphical schema languages known as "Entity Relationship Diagram" and "UML Class Diagram" and tools that help to draw them. Recommending a tool that can do it all for you is not [on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). What exactly did you find wrong about EER mapping or UML class mapping? What did you try already? Right now your question looks unclear to me. BTW some people say that the smartest tool that is free and can solve it is [your brain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871449/what-tools-should-i-use-to-visualize-structure-of-my-code)

Comment: Very simple, and you don't need something as complex as UML or EER diagrams, your data "model" will always look like multiple unrelated trees, with each root entity as a tree root...

Comment: Yet simple but not the answer I was after, I am looking for a way to visualize the data trees with related fields (I know the data structure if dynamic and can change but it would be beneficial to visualize it)

Comment: There's contradiction in your question - there's no schema in Google Datastore by design. Datastore has KeyPropery and StructuredProperty that may be used to convey a meaning (schema), but entities themselves can be joined in any way. In your example User has Activity and Activity has Comment. In datastore it would be represented by User -> Activity -> Comment entity graph. But there can also be just Comment or Activity -> Comment, or even something absurd Comment -> Activity -> User. Datastore doesn't care. It has no schema.