# Architexa doesn't work (unable to load class com.architexa.diagrams.editors.RSEMultiPageEditor)

Tags: java, eclipse, uml

I am trying to use Architexa, but it doesn't work. When I try to open a new layered diagram for example, I get this error:

> Plug-in com.architexa.diagrams was unable to load class com.architexa.diagrams.editors.RSEMultiPageEditor

And for example when I right click a java class and hover over Open in diagram, that should give me the choice to click in which diagram I want to open the java class, none option is presented to me for me to click.

Did anybody face this problem before?

This tool would be really helpful to me, because it gives me the opportunity to construct the whole path from a class to another class by showing me all the important aspects, like the name of the method, the name of class and also package. If nobody faced this problem before, maybe someone knows an alternative to this tool, that has the same behavior as the one mentioned above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a few days I figured out that I had to install jdk 1.7 in order for architexa to work. I also set the path in the environment variables and VOILA!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to solve your Architexa installation problem on [Architexa Forums](http://www.architexa.com/forums/) or by contacting the Architexa support (see link at the bottom of http://www.architexa.com/support/faq)

Recommending *"..a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource.."* is [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here, but you can find useful

- [Stack Overflow: What tools should I use to visualize structure of my code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871449/what-tools-should-i-use-to-visualize-structure-of-my-code)
- [Stack Overflow: UML Diagram Tool - Eclipse plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600097/uml-diagram-tool-eclipse-plugin)

---

Personally I've found very useful and quite easy to use the [ObjectAid UML Explorer for Eclipse](http://www.objectaid.com/) if you want to quickly see reverse engineered static class structure of your code as UML class diagrams in just a few search, drag & drop, right click, double click commands...

e.g. finding all classes using the class I see on the screen and to add their subset into the class diagram in ObjectAid it is a matter of using right click, select popup menu references in project, in the found resultset use select all, show in explorer, drag drop to the class diagram - 5? seconds